# How can I run python downloaded from the official site with VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used to use the python downloaded from Microsoft Store, which worked properly in VScode.

However, when I shift to the python 3.9.5 version downloaded from the official site, VScode doesn't seem to be able to find the correct path and I just can't run any python code, including the command "python3 -V".
[python3.9.5 has been downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKyhC.png)
[I couldn't run python codes or commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SkQy.png)

Comment: You need to add python in environment variable

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean.
Would be glad if provide a more detailed instructions.

Comment: https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: @YungYung It looks like you installed python, but you will need to add the executable to PATH. Try reading through this https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Goion for your help, and my problem is now solved

Comment: And of course @Smurphy0000 as well.